# GeoSPARQL or stSPARQL to get length of line object

Tags: sparql, geospatial, spatial, geosparql

Is there any way to calculate the total distance of a line object (e.g. coastline) using GeoSPARQL or stSPARQL?

Comment: It seems that no, though [Simple Features](http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=25354) mentions `ST_Length`.